# Tortoisesvn "https://username@www.server.com:port" somehow storing old authorization data

Tags: svn, authentication, tortoisesvn

I've recently changed my SVN password, because I forgot it and needed to do a checkout on a machine where I had no stored authentication data.

I went back to my old machine and went to tortoise SVN settings>>Saved Data>>Authentication Data>>Clear all.
I expected to simply be able to enter my new password and merrily continue along.
It does ask for my new password, but doesn't use it.

I checked the serverlog and its logging 'Access denied' because a user tried to log in with an incorrect password.

I've gone to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion and manually deleted the auth folder, to try and clear its memory of my password. Maybe I did and it is now sending an empty password string, but whatever it is sending it is not the new password I entered.

I then tried making a fresh checkout of the SVN.
I can do this using "server:port" or "username@server:port" in ye'olde days when I did checkouts with a command line I would always use username@server. So when I made the checkout with tortoise I continued doing so, but the fresh checkout, would ask for a username and password and then proceed to use the old one anyway.

When I tried to checkout with "server:port" and entered my new password when prompted tortoise merrily proceeded to checkout and re-download the entire SVN.

I can now copy the changed files over and commit, so its not really an issue anymore. But now I'm sitting here waiting for several gigs of files download and wondering if this is some sort of bug or feature I know nothing about. And while I'm waiting anyway I might as well ask someone about this.

Comment: Try deleting the user from the server, restarting the server, and then re-adding him (with the exact same username, and the new password).